# Button Value attribute not taking css

Tags: html, css

Hello I need to apply css on a button using value attribute.
But it's not taking the css

```css
button[value=Export List to Excel] {
  margin-top: 14px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" id="cp_export_excel" name="cp_export_excel" value="Export List to Excel" class="btn btn-warning form-submit icon-before"><span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-export" aria-hidden="true"></span> Export List to Excel</button>
```

How will I implement this one. I need to specifically use value attribute only.Can somebody please help.

Comment: Try adding quote marks around your value: `button[value="Export List to Excel"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put your value expression in quotes, as your spaces breaks CSS rule match:

```css
button[value="Export List to Excel"] {
  margin-top: 14px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" id="cp_export_excel" name="cp_export_excel" value="Export List to Excel" class="btn btn-warning form-submit icon-before"><span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-export" aria-hidden="true"></span> Export List to Excel</button>
```